# My image does not display when using handlebars

Tags: html, image, handlebars.js, src

Below is my handlebar page and image of my file structure, I am not able to load any images using these handlebars, not sure what is causing this:

```
<div>
    <h1>HI</h1>
    <img src="images/normal.gif">
</div>
```

main hanlebars:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Form validation</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
        {{{body}}}
    
</body>
</html>
```

The error I get is:

```
localhost/:12          GET http://localhost:3000/images/normal.gif 404 (Not Found)
```

If I use the full path I get:

```
Not allowed to load local resource:
```

[image]

I don't know why this does not work. I tried /images/normal.gif. Also tried adding other images which are part of the people folder but it just displays a broken image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images folder should have been in public folder because in app.js static was using /public

Answer (score 5):

place images folder inside the public folder and register it inside the index.js file.

```
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public/images")));
```

then use image

```html
<img src='images/normal.gif'>
```